# ssh freezes when trying to connect to my server?

Tags: server, 18.04, ssh, openssh

I'm trying to connect to my remote server.
First I generated the ssh keys public and private from the cpanel, then I downloaded the private key to the **/home/anass/.ssh** folder.
and then from the terminal I used the private key:

```
anass@guest:~/.ssh$ **ssh -vvv -i id_rsa username@149.202.XXX.XXX**
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "149.202.XXX.XXX" port 22*
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 149.202.XXX.XXX [149.202.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 149.202.XXX.XXX port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 149.202.XXX.XXX port 22: Connection timed out
```

Can anyone help me out, Please !

Comment: Do you and the server both have an internet connection?

Comment: @j-money Yes Of course, My website is already running.

Comment: Does the port 22 is open in the firewall of the server?

Comment: @pa4080 is there a way to check ports from cpanel ?

Comment: `netstat -lntu` to list open ports (though iirc netstat is deprecated [needs fact checking])

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with c-panel.

Comment: Yep, @j-money is right, you can test that from outside: [Check status of one port on remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168317/check-status-of-one-port-on-remote-host). I'm almost sure this is the problem. How do you usually access the remote rerver?

Comment: please install nmap and try sudo nmap -p 22 -sS 149.202.xxx.xxx and edit with command output

Comment: @pa4080 I usually access the server using cpanel, or FTP client (filezilla) for uploads...

Comment: @Gravemind 
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-02-08 21:09 +01
Nmap scan report for XXX.adk-media.com (149.202.XXX.XXX)
Host is up (0.083s latency).

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.27 seconds

Comment: @El-Anass you have a firewall issue

Comment: @Gravemind Thank you, But how can I fix it ?

Comment: @El-Anass it depends on OS  on your remote server.

Comment: @Gravemind It's a Linux server

Comment: @El-Anass Debian-like? Fedora-like? LFS?

Comment: @Gravemind it's a "CloudLinux System 64 bits". that's the only information I found about the server, beside the Kernel version :/ maybe I should contact the host provider about this issue. Thank you so much.